# Textfiles C++ Editing the very first line

Tags: c++, append, text-files

Example of Textfile:

5 <- I need to edit this number.

0

1

0

6

(Sample Code Not Whole Program)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() { 
int i;
cin>>i;
    std::fstream file("example.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
    file.seekp(0);

    file << i;
    return 0;
}
```

With this code the number is added here:
(example.txt)

5

0

1

0

67 <<

Please note that from the bottom the numbers will keep increasing so it has to be always the first line not that specific 5.

Please Help 
Thanks

Comment: You're using `ios::app`. That means "append". The write cursor is moved to the end of the file.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have opened the file in a mode that requests that all new data is *appended* to the end of the file (`std::ios::app`). Don't specify that flag if you don't want to always append.

Note that you will encounter problems if the new line you're writing is not *exactly* the same length as the existing line. In the case where it's a different length, you will have to copy and rewrite the entire remainder of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your help it worked by removing std::ios::app, on that problem with just adding a few spaces will solve the problem for now. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but do you think that this will work? when reading the integer check if  num is 10 (don't think it will go so far as 100 ) if it exceeds 10 then will insert a \n in the text file.