# overwrite first line of textfile (c#)

Tags: c#, string, file, overwrite

I have a textfile (obj-file) which is auto generated.

It looks like this:

```
# File generated by IfcOpenShell v0.7.0-e508fb44
g 2O2Fr$t4X7Zf8NOew3FNtn
s 1
v 0 -0.417 0
v 0 -5.55111512312578e-17 0
v 2.63496916504281 -5.55111512312578e-17 0
v 2.63496916504281 -0.417 0
v 2.63496916504281 -0.417 0
v 2.63496916504281 -5.55111512312578e-17 0
v 2.63496916504281 -5.55111512312578e-17 2.42
v 2.63496916504281 -0.417 2.42
...
```

I need to insert the string `mtllib ./model_0.mtl` at the beginning of the file.
Since the first line is always a comment i thought i could overwrite it like this.

`# File generated by IfcOpenShell v0.7.0-e508fb44`

`mtllib ./model_0.mtl`

The problem is I don't know how to achive this, how do I open the file in special way?
I want to avoid reading the whole file in changing a few characters and writing the whole file out..

this is similar, but does not seem to help too much (I'm using c#)
[Textfiles C++ Editing the very first line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642274/textfiles-c-editing-the-very-first-line)

Comment: Unless these files are gigantic, you should just read all and write line+all. You're not going to notice the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing a text file in place through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104324/editing-a-text-file-in-place-through-c-sharp)

Comment: If you don't want to read and write the whole file, you can look at `FileStream.Position`, `FileStream.Read()`, `FileStream.Write()`.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you're changing the *length* of the first line, all subsequent lines have to change position in the file *anyway*, to use up the space.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using *Linq*; if file is not that large

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

string fileName = @"c:\myFile.txt";

var newLines = new string[] {"mtllib ./model_0.mtl"} // first line
  .Concat(File
    .ReadLines(fileName) // all file
    .Skip(1))            // except the very first line
    .ToList();

File.WriteAllLines(fileName, newLines);
```

If file is *large* and so `.ToList()` - *materialization* - is not a good option we can save the file and then rename it:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

string fileName = @"c:\myFile.txt";

var newLines = new string[] {"mtllib ./model_0.mtl"} // first line
  .Concat(File
    .ReadLines(fileName) // all file
    .Skip(1));           // except the very first line
    
// Save under different name
File.WriteAllLines(fileName + "~", newLines);

File.Move(fileName + "~", fileName, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not too large simply use

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path); 
lines[0] = "mtllib ./model_0.mtl"; // you might want to check if lines.Length > 0 
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String newLine="mtllib ./model_0.mtl" ;

string content = File.ReadAllText(Path);
content = newLine + "\n" + content;      
File.WriteAllText(Path, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```cs
byte[] mtlPathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"mtllib ./model_{modelId}.mtl\n#");
        
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(objPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    fs.Write(mtlPathBytes, 0, mtlPathBytes.Length);
}
```